# How To Backup And Restore DataBase With FILE STREAM Using SMO in C#

Tags: c#, sql, backup, smo, database-restore

How can i backup and restore a database with file stream Using SMO in C#.
i found some attributes in Server Class in SMO Like "FilestreamLevel" and "FilestreamShareName"
but i do not know how to use them.

please help
and thanks for all

Comment: can you show us the code you have tried/written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do to backup a database that is using [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx):

> Because FILESTREAM is implemented as a varbinary(max) column and integrated directly into the Database Engine, most SQL Server management tools and functions work without modification for FILESTREAM data. For example, you can use all backup and recovery models with FILESTREAM data, and the FILESTREAM data is backed up with the structured data in the database

and as the next statement points out, you actually have to do more to *exclude* filestream data from the backup:

> If you do not want to back up FILESTREAM data with relational data, you can use a partial backup to exclude FILESTREAM filegroups.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to [this site](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1849), which will give you some basic idea to do Database Backup and Restore with SMO